# Looping regressions in R

Tags: r, loops, regression

What is the best way to re-write this code into a loop?

```
a.data1 <- read.csv('outdata1.csv')
growth.sub.QOG1 <- merge(QOG, a.data1, by = c('year', 'country'), all = F)
growth.re1 <- plm(NY.GDP.PCAP.KD.ZG ~ log(Enrolment.in.all.programmes..Tertiary..Total)    + law + engineering + log(SP.POP.TOTL) + lp.legor
 ,data=growth.sub.QOG1, model="random")
summary(growth.re1)
eststo(growth.re1)


a.data2 <- read.csv('outdata2.csv')
growth.sub.QOG2 <- merge(QOG, a.data2, by = c('year', 'country'), all = F)
growth.re2 <- plm(NY.GDP.PCAP.KD.ZG ~ log(Enrolment.in.all.programmes..Tertiary..Total) + law + 
                  engineering + log(SP.POP.TOTL) + lp.legor
                    ,data=growth.sub.QOG2, model="random")
summary(growth.re2)
eststo(growth.re2)

a.data3 <- read.csv('outdata3.csv')
growth.sub.QOG3 <- merge(QOG, a.data3, by = c('year', 'country'), all = F)
growth.re3 <- plm(NY.GDP.PCAP.KD.ZG ~ log(Enrolment.in.all.programmes..Tertiary..Total) + law + 
                  engineering + log(SP.POP.TOTL) + lp.legor
                    ,data=growth.sub.QOG3, model="random")
summary(growth.re3)
eststo(growth.re3)
```

I tried to do something like this:

```
for (i  in 1:10) {
a.data[i] <- read.csv('outdata[i].csv')
growth.sub.QOG[i] <- merge(QOG, a.data[i], by = c('year', 'country'), all = F)
growth.re[i] <- plm(NY.GDP.PCAP.KD.ZG ~ log(Enrolment.in.all.programmes..Tertiary..Total) + law + 
                  engineering + log(SP.POP.TOTL) + lp.legor
                    ,data=growth.sub.QOG[i], model="random")
summary(growth.re[i])
eststo(growth.re[i])
}
```

but it didn't work, what is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It would help to separate the data import and modelling steps. You will need to use `paste` to construct the filenames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct your file names.

```
files <- paste("outdata", 1:3, ".csv", sep = "")
#alternatively, use list.files/dir as suggested by Chris
```

How you structure the rest of your code depends upon whether or not you care about those intermediate variables.  I've assumed that you do, so you have lots of separate loops.  If you don't care, merge the lapply statements.

Read in the data.

```
all_data <- lapply(file, read.csv)
```

Merge.

```
merged <- lapply(all_data, function(data) 
{
  merge(QOG, data, by = c('year', 'country'), all = FALSE)
})
```

Model.

```
models <- lapply(merged, function(data)
{
  plm(
    NY.GDP.PCAP.KD.ZG ~ log(Enrolment.in.all.programmes..Tertiary..Total) + law + engineering + log(SP.POP.TOTL) + lp.legor,
    data, 
    model = "random"
  )
})
```

Display some output.

```
(summaries <- lapply(models, summary))
(eststos <- lapply(models, eststo))
```

Comment: @NilsOlve: For each of the answers that have been useful to you, click the upwards arrow on the left to upvote them.  Then choose the best answer and click the tick to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

some sample data would have been nice but spontaneously I see the error that you won't be able to read in the file like that. try:

```
  file.name <- paste('outdata', i, '.csv', sep='')
  variable <- paste('a.data', i, sep='')
  data.in <- read.csv(file.name)
```

if you want to store it in a dynamically created variable this works like this:

```
  assign(variable, data.in)
```

this should fix the first part!

Comment: Using assign will mean that there are lots of different variables containing each dataset, which clutters up the worksapce and is hard to work with.  It would be better to read them in to a list of data frames with `lapply` + `read.csv`.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works

```
#instance of your directory
datadir  <-"D:/Regression"
# set working directory, i.e. R knows where to get the data files 
setwd(datadir)

csvfiles <- list.files(datadir,".csv$")

#read data from datadir
for(x in csvfiles)
{
  assign(gsub(" ","",sub(".csv","",x)),read.csv(x,header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=F,sep=";"))
}

data<-c("outdata1,outdata2,outdata3,...")

i<-1
for(x in data)
{
  tmp <- eval(parse(text=x))
  growth.sub.QOG[i]<- merge(QOG,tmp, by = c('year', 'country'), all = F)
  growth.re[i] <- plm(NY.GDP.PCAP.KD.ZG ~ log(Enrolment.in.all.programmes..Tertiary..Total)
                    + law + engineering + log(SP.POP.TOTL) + lp.legor,
                    data=tmp, model="random") 
  Summary[i]<-summary(growth.re[i]) 
  Est[i]<-eststo(growth.re[i]) 
  rm(tmp)
  i<-i+1
}
```

Good luck and let me know if you encounter some error...

Comment: Thank you for helping me, I think we're halfway there. But it doesn't work; I think I spotted one mistake. But I don't know how to correct it, I would be really happy if you could take a look at it. The mistake I spotted is in this second loop. This line: `data=tmp, model="random")` should be somewhat like this: `data=growth.sub.QOG[i], model="random")` and this leads me do this error message: Error in growth.sub.QOG[i] <- merge(QOG, tmp, by = c("year", "country"),  : 
  object 'growth.sub.QOG' not found

Comment: I see... did you declare growth.sub.QOG somewhere before the loop? even QOG? If not, you have to create an empty data frame with the same size as you want.

Comment: growth.re should also predefined before the loop otherwise it can't be recognized.